# Jenkins: prevent from reloading configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am currently doing an analysis whether jenkins could fit for our needs.
Therefore I need to know something about (NOT) reloading configurations:

I know that there is an explicit way to reload a configuration (via WebGUI and CLI).
BUT:
Is there also a way to PREVENT Jenkins from reloading configs?

One requirement is that the CI-System reads in all config-files (general and job-configs) ONCE at the start of the ci-system. And afterwards a modification of the config-files shall take NO effect!

Do you know whether this is already the case (except I press that button under "manage Jenkins" | "reload Configuration from hard disk" [exact options might sound a little different because I only have a German version here])

Would be very thankful for your help,
Lukas

Comment: Why is it important to you that it never reads the config during run time? That sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: Because e.g. someone might (accidentally) change a config-file with an old/other job. Then in the overview job might appear as "ok" but actually then this is not true..
If there are a lot of jobs being build every day, this one false information can have bad side effects..

Comment: When you're afraid that user can change job configs then you should consider this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins

Comment: yes, I would do that definately too.
But what if someone changes the config-files itsself (the xml-files).?
Will this be relevant to the running instance of jenkins?
This was my actual question.

Comment: The only way is to keep security policy, giving access to editing configuration to the people. As for xml configuration files by itself, it's still security policies, when you need to have server accessed only by the needed people.

Answer (score 0):

I run a Git repo to control the config.xml files so have experience of the xml files changing while Jenkins is running.

I can confidently state that Jenkins will not reread the config.xml file unless you specifically ask it to via the UI or cli. In fact if the config is changed via the UI any changes that has been done to the config.xml file will be overwritten with the in-memory version.